# Issues using a non-Mac mouse with MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, bluetooth, mouse

The mouse I'm currently using is the Logitech Anywhere 2s mouse recommended by this [youtuber](https://youtu.be/tNCwvihWO78).

When I use it for prolong amounts of time, I find VERY significant connection lag issues no matter whether using the USB Unifying receiver / Bluetooth option.

Wondering if anyone have faced the same issue and their steps to resolve it.

### Hardware/Software I'm using :

- MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2020, Two Thunderbolt 3 ports) [1.4 GHz
  Quad-Core Intel Core i5]
- macOS Big Sur Version 11.2
- Logitech Anywhere 2s mouse
- Vention USB HUB USB C to HDMI

*Note that I have tested it with old Macbook Air (that comes with the old USB port) and it works perfectly

Comment: So the lag occurs even when you're plugging it directly (well, via a Hub) to the Mac? And you've turned off Bluetooth? I have heard stories about USB C cables and Bluetooth interfering with each other.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried utilizing the Logitech drivers?

https://support.logi.com/hc/en-us/articles/360024690714--Downloads-MX-Anywhere-2S-Wireless-Mouse